# Is it possible to dynamically add 2 rows at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

[image]

I have  2 rows on our form that must be repeated 4 different times.

So, rather than show 8 rows, at same time, is it possible to show first 2 rows with a button that says, "Add additional rows"

If a user clicks the button, 2 rows are automatically added.

From the code below, each code beginning with ...and ends with  displays 4 times.

The 2 rows display 8 times combined

The rows don't always get filled. So, it will be nice to have the users click a button to add additional 2 rows if needed.

I have a js that can add one row but I can't get it to add 2 at same time.

Here is how the code with ... I am trying to add automatically looks like.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function () {
        var index = 1;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#more").click(function () {
                addRow(1)
                //alert($("#form1").html()); Uncomment to view updated form html
            });
        });


        function addRow(rowCount) {
            for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                index = index + 1;
                $("#form1").append($("#template").html().replace(/_1/g, "_" + index));
            }
        }

    });//]]>  

</script>

      <div id="template">
                  <table border="1" bordercolor="black" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
            <td>

      <table style="border-top-width:2px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000">
            <tr valign="top">
                 <td valign="middle" style="font-size:large;font-weight:bold;" class="style4"></td>
                <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Line #<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox24" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:135px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                   Code<br />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox38" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:125px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Document Reference<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox25" runat="server" Width="45px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Line<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox26" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:115px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    PC COMM LN<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox27" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:115px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Vendor Invoice #<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox28" runat="server" Width="85px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                  Fund<br />
                      <asp:DropDownList id="txtfund" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Agency<br />
                      <asp:DropDownList id="txtagency" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Org.<br />
                     <asp:DropDownList id="txtorg" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Sub<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox32" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Activity<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox33" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Object<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox34" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:115px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Sub<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox35" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:115px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                   Rev Source<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox36" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;">
                    Sub<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox37" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>   

        <table style="border-top-width:2px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000">
            <tr valign="top">
                 <td valign="middle" style="font-size:large;font-weight:bold;" class="style4"></td>
                <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    <br /><br />Job #<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox39" runat="server" Width="45px" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:135px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    <br />
                    Rept<br />Category<br />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox40" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    <br /><br />BS Acct<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox41" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                   <br /><br /> DISC<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox42" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    <br />Description (30) Spaces<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox403" runat="server" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this,30);" onChange="javascript:Count(this,30);" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="2" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    <br /><br />Quant.<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox44" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                   <br /><br /> Amount<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox45" runat="server" Width="55px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                   Inc<br />/<br />Dec<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox46" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;">

                    P<br />/<br />F<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox47" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>   
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>        
        </div>

      <a href="#" id="more">Add More Rows</a>
     <div class="noprint" style="border-top-width:2px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000"">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSAP" Text="Save" OnClientClick=" return validate()" />
             <asp:Button ID="btnClear" OnClick="ClearFilter" height="27px" Text="Reset" runat="server" class="btn" /> 
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancel" Text="Exit Form" />
             <!-- Results -->
            <asp:Label ID="lblResult" style ="font-weight:bold; font-size:large" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </div>
   </form>
```

Here is a link to fiddle created by Mohammed(thanks)

http://jsfiddle.net/TE6ac/

I also found this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BE5Lr/

If I duplicate the ...

I am close to what I am looking for. Problem is I have many more .. and wouldn't know where to start and stop.

Comment: Please, provide minimal examples.

Comment: I'm sure this is easy, but I can't understand your question as you have a LOOONG one, get straight into the point with minimal code examples plz.
P.S: I've created a JsFiddle for you, kindly style and modify it and provide the link inside your question
http://jsfiddle.net/TE6ac/

Comment: Thank you Mohammed. I have added some styles. Did you want me to add more html codes? There is a whole lot more than that but I just showed the 2 tables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dharmavir/9nHbs/
it should help.!

```
<div id="template">
                  <table border="1" bordercolor="black" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
            <td>

      <table style="border-top-width:2px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000">
            <tr valign="top">
                 <td valign="middle" style="font-size:large;font-weight:bold;" class="style4"></td>
                <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Line #<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox24" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:135px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                   Code<br />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox38" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:125px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Document Reference<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox25" runat="server" Width="45px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Line<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox26" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:115px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    PC COMM LN<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox27" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:115px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Vendor Invoice #<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox28" runat="server" Width="85px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                  Fund<br />
                      <asp:DropDownList id="txtfund" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Agency<br />
                      <asp:DropDownList id="txtagency" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Org.<br />
                     <asp:DropDownList id="txtorg" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Sub<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox32" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Activity<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox33" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Object<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox34" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:115px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    Sub<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox35" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:115px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                   Rev Source<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox36" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;">
                    Sub<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox37" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>   

        <table style="border-top-width:2px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000">
            <tr valign="top">
                 <td valign="middle" style="font-size:large;font-weight:bold;" class="style4"></td>
                <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    <br /><br />Job #<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox39" runat="server" Width="45px" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:135px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    <br />
                    Rept<br />Category<br />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox40" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    <br /><br />BS Acct<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox41" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                   <br /><br /> DISC<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox42" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    <br />Description (30) Spaces<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox403" runat="server" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this,30);" onChange="javascript:Count(this,30);" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="2" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                    <br /><br />Quant.<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox44" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                   <br /><br /> Amount<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox45" runat="server" Width="55px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;border-right-width:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#000000">
                   Inc<br />/<br />Dec<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox46" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
                 <td style="width:105px;">

                    P<br />/<br />F<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox47" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>   
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>        
        </div>

<table id="sometable">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="anothertable">
<tr>
<td> some other table </td>
</tr>
</table>
      <a href="#" id="more">Add More Rows</a>
     <div class="noprint" style="border-top-width:2px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#000000"">

      </div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
   </form>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var index = 1;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#more").click(function () {
                addRow(1);
                //alert($("#form1").html()); Uncomment to view updated form html
            });
        });


        function addRow(rowCount) {
            for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                index = index + 1;
$("#sometable").append($("#template").html().replace(/_1/g, "_" + index));
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Answers on stackoverflow should be self-contained. Add your answer here and link to a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Dharmavirsinh for your help. My big problem is that I have several tables <table>...</table>. 

However, I only want to add 2 rows on just 2 of those tables. How do I do that without dupplicating all the tables?

Comment: Mathletics, I don't know if your comment was directed at me but if you read Mohammed's comment, he asked that I add that link to my question.

Comment: Hi Dharmavirsinh, I was able to modify yours slightly to get it to work.

However, I still have one major issue. Instead of adding the 2 rows immediately below the existing rows, it adds it outside the Save button. 

I would like to post the current entire code I am using but I wait till I get the OK.

Thanks again.

Comment: @Mathletics I understand what you're trying to explain me but sometimes just a fiddle link means everything and I just wanted to help.
Point is when one wants to help and don't have much time to describe/write what all he is trying to explain - at such time just a fiddle link works..!
Nevermind if it's rule of stackoverflow I will take care and I would really appreciate if you can redirect me to a link where I can read all dos and donts of stackoverflow.

Comment: @Kenny can you to the fiddle and add some of your javascript code with which you're struggling? because right now if I go there what all I see is just html code, probably you need to hit on "update" button and post the updated URL. That way it will be easier for anyone to help you out.

Comment: I tried to update the fiddle with current info but it seems it is not persistent. 

I added a new/modified code, clicked Update, saw updated changes but when I went back to take a look again, I don't see the changes I made. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have just posted an an image of what it looks like right now. As you can see, I am able to add 2 rows, thanks to your code but the rows are being added after Save/Reset/Exit form buttons. They need to be added directly below the existing 2 rows. I have updated the form I posted with your code. I know it is getting too long, sorry. Don't know how else to show it.

Comment: @Kenny take a look at this, I have updated jsfiddle.
I am assuming that you want to append the rows next to each other and not at the bottom of the form. If I am wrong update fiddle and give me updated URL.
http://jsfiddle.net/dharmavir/TE6ac/4/

Comment: Hi Dharmavirsinh,

Yes, that's exactly what we are after but the sample on jsfiddle doesn't work. 

When I click on Add more Rows, it doens't give an errors but doesn't add the rows either.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hi @Kenny, I think you did not see updated fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/dharmavir/TE6ac/4/ 
it adds rows and works as expected. Please check and reply.

Comment: Hi Dharmavirsinh,

Is it possible that I am looking at the wrong link?

When I click on "Add More Rows", nothing happens.

Perhaps, you can post the latest code here?

Comment: I thank you very much for your help and more importantly, your patience. I still don't see why it isn't working.

Again, I click "Add More Rows" and no new rows are added. No errors but not adding the needed rows.

I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Kenny that sounds wired but I tested on IE9, Chrome 19 and Firefox 12 and found that fiddle working...!
Just make sure that your javascript is not disabled in your browser and you should not be running on Windows 2003 with Enhanced Internet security, I have noticed such js problem if I am somewhere on Windows Server family OS. Basically if you click on JS fiddle link which I gave you should work as I tested same on all browsers as I mentioned above. If still not may be a different workstation..!

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I guess the reason it doesn't work for me is because I am running ie8, not 9

Comment: @Kenny were you able to check on Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: I was able to run that in IE8 w/o compatibility mode but when I turned on compatilibity mode it stopped because of following error:
------------------------------
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; MSN OptimizedIE8;ENIN)
Timestamp: Wed, 30 May 2012 14:59:23 UTC


Message: Access is denied.

Line: 134
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://jsfiddle.net/codemirror/js/select.js

Comment: so basically that's problem due to being executed from jsfiddle - if you copy paste that code locally and run from some file, it should work well.

Comment: Sorry, it took a long time to accept this. Even though it still didn't work, I truly appreciate all your efforts.

Comment: @Kenny I am sure if you non-IE browser it will work and for IE as well it should work as it worked for me but I am not sure what can be done for your environment. If possible I would surely like to debug by accessing your environment. If anytime you need help let me know I can be available on some remote access tool for the help.